# Mage_AdminNotification.csv already exists

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, extensions

I tried to install the Locale_Mage_community_de_DE extension but it failed with:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Locale_Mage_community_de_DE' is invalid
'./app/locale/de_DE/Mage_AdminNotification.csv' already exists
```

What can I do?

Comment: After the installation check what is in the backup and what is in the new installed file and copy the differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up the files in `app/locale/de_DE` and delete the folder `de_DE` entirely.
Then try to install the language pack again.
**EDIT**
Also delete app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/de_DE (thanks @PiTheNumber - I forgot about that)

Comment: Also delete `/app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/de_DE`

Comment: Yeah...@PiTheNumber Thanks. I updated the answer.